# MS Word: Set style font size to default / from underlying properties

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, colors, styles, editing

When I create a style in Word, the font size of the style gets set to whatever the font size of the text I've selected is. e.g. if I create a style while 13pt text is selected, the new style text will start with 13pt.

Is there a way to make it so that the style only applies the other properties and does not change font size?

e.g. A style to make something bold, underlined and colored red will be a different font size if I apply it to text that is of font size 14, and to that of font size 11. (i.e. stays that font size in both cases instead of always going to a particular font size)

Answer (score 0):

### A *paragraph* style will always have a size element. A *character* style need not.

A character style will be based on the default paragraph font with any changes that you make in the create style dialog.

[image: screenshot of style dialog]

The default when you open the dialog is to create a paragraph style, but when you change it to character style, the size and font both blank out. You can add a particular font and size if you want.

For more:

- My page on [Styles in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview)
- Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on [Managing Styles](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/ManageStyles.htm)